# How does a DIY holographic display work?

Tags: optics, hologram

I made a holographic display with [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9t0cOYvOy4M), but now I'm wondering if the 4 projections on each side of the pyramid do interfere with each other. Can you get just the same image if you only project one video (instead of [4 video's](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y60mfBvXCj8)) on a single plate or are these different video's necessary to get a 3D view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This technique is indeed not true 3D, but the reflection on each peace of plastic creates a virtual image in the center of the pyramid. For most videos for this setup they use a periodic rotating animation, which can just be delayed one quarter of a period for each side of the pyramid to easily create the illusion that you are viewing the animation from another angle when you move around it. This might trick your mind in believing that it is 3D while moving around it, while a single reflection only looks like a 2D hologram.